# Running into errors when making client program using udp

Tags: c

I am making a client program using udp in c. I made an outline and tried to make plenty of notes in the code so you know what I am doing. When I run it I get a bunch or errors revolving around declarations and definitions. I tried moving the constants and include statements into a header, but I am also relatively new to c programming so I don't know if that had any affect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

// Define Constants
#define SERVER_PORT 52555
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

// Function to send the file to the server
void SendFile(const char* SourceFileName, int SocketDescriptor, struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress) {
    // Declare variables
    FILE* sourceFile;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    // Open SourceFileName
    sourceFile = fopen(SourceFileName, "r");
    if (sourceFile == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening source file");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Loop until EOF
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, sourceFile) != NULL) {
        // Send Line
        sendto(SocketDescriptor, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress));
    }
    
    // Send EOF
    sendto(SocketDescriptor, "EOF", 3, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&ServerAddress, sizeof(ServerAddress));
    
    fclose(sourceFile);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Declare variables
    int SocketDescriptor;
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;

    // Read Argc & Argv
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s server-name source-filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create Socket
    SocketDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (SocketDescriptor == -1) {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create Server Socket
    memset(&ServerAddress, 0, sizeof(ServerAddress));
    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    SendFile(argv[3], SocketDescriptor, ServerAddress);
    
    printf("File sent, waiting for confirmation...\n");

    // Receive Confirmation
    char confirmation[BUFFER_SIZE];
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(ServerAddress);
    recvfrom(SocketDescriptor, confirmation, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&ServerAddress, &addr_len);

    // Handle Confirmation
    char confirmation[BUFFER_SIZE];
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(ServerAddress);
    recvfrom(SocketDescriptor, confirmation, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&ServerAddress, &addr_len);

    // Basic confirmation if/else

    // Close Socket
    pclose(SocketDescriptor);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors that I am receiving when I try to test the code above. Any help on fixing the code would be greatly appreciated.

```
ftpclient.c: In function ‘main’:
ftpclient.c:70:10: error: redeclaration of ‘confirmation’ with no linkage
     char confirmation[BUFFER_SIZE];
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ftpclient.c:65:10: note: previous declaration of ‘confirmation’ was here
     char confirmation[BUFFER_SIZE];
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ftpclient.c:71:15: error: redefinition of ‘addr_len’
     socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(ServerAddress);
               ^~~~~~~~
ftpclient.c:66:15: note: previous definition of ‘addr_len’ was here
     socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(ServerAddress);
               ^~~~~~~~
ftpclient.c:83:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pclose’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     pclose(SocketDescriptor);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ftpclient.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:812:26: note: expected ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’} but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the source you're compiling? There's no reference to `close()`.

Comment: unless putty messed up it should be let me check real quick

Comment: it is the correct code and error messages

Comment: You have `char confirmation[BUFFER_SIZE];` twice: Once after `// Receive Confirmation` and again after `// Handle Confirmation`.

Comment: You've declared the same variables `confirmation` and `addr_len` multiple times in the same scope -- you can't do that.  And why are you calling [`pclose`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3p.html)?

Comment: The argument to `pclose()` should be a `FILE*` variable returned by `popen()`. Use `close()` to close a file descriptor or socket descriptor.

Comment: In your main function you're writing the same exact code for receive and handle confirmation, which is what's causing your errors. You either have to give the variables different names or just use one and discard the other